# Retryable grpc-web server-streaming rpc

Tags: rxjs, grpc, grpc-web

I am trying to wrap a grpc-web server-streaming client with rxjs.Observable and be able to perform retries if say the server returns an error.

Consider the following code.

```js
  // server
  foo = (call: (call: ServerWritableStream<FooRequest, Empty>): void => {
    if (!call.request?.getMessage()) {
      call.emit("error", { code: StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, message: "Invalid request" })
    }

    for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      call.write(new FooResponse())
    }
    call.end()
  }
 
  // client 
  test("should not end on retry", (done) => {
    new Observable(obs => {
      const call =  new FooClient("http://localhost:8080").foo(new FooRequest())
      call.on("data", data => obs.next(data))
      call.on("error", err => {
        console.log("server emitted error")
        obs.error(err)
      })
      call.on("end", () => {
        console.log("server emitted end")
        obs.complete()
      })
    })
    .pipe(retryWhen(<custom retry policy>))
    .subscribe(
        _resp => () => {},
        _error => {
          console.log("source observable error")
          done()
        },
        () => {
          console.log("source observable completed(?)")
          done()
        })
  })
  
  // output
  server emitted error
  server emitted end
  source observable completed(?)
```

The server emits the "end" event after(?) emitting "error", so it seems like I have to remove the "end" handler from the source observable.

What would be an "Rx-y" way to end/complete the stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I ended up removing the "end" event handler and replaced it with "status", if the server returns an `OK` status code (which signals the end of the stream) then the observable is completed.

```js
new Observable(obs => {
  const call =  new FooClient("http://localhost:8080").foo(new FooRequest())
  call.on("data", data => obs.next(data))
  call.on("error", err => obs.error(err))
  call.on("status", status: grpcWeb.Status => {
    if (status.code == grpcWeb.StatusCode.OK) {
      return observer.complete()
    }
  })
})
```